# Facebook like plugin not displaying faces for non facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, facebook-like

I have added Facebook social plugin like button to a page on a private website, and like & share are working as as expected. Clicking like is increasing like counter, it is possible to "undo" like, sharing is working normally. The problem is with faces, only my "fb face" is shown. Although my fb friends have liked the page which increased like counter, I can still only see my face (and each of them can only see their own "fb face")

I have created new Facebook page, liked the page, together with a same friend who liked my original page. I added another like button to my page, with data-href pointing to the facebook page which we liked and both of our faces are shown.

To summarize, when people like Facebook pages like counter is updated and their faces are shown.
When people like my page like counter is updated but everyone can see only his own face.

What needs to be done on non fb pages for faces to be shown?

I have added all the necessary meta og and fb tags, I have checked *https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/* and *http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=* for my page and everything looks as expected, except there is just one fb face...

I have recreated the problem on a publicly accessible test page http://dmmicko.webs.com/fb/fbtest2.html (note that this is a free website, so like has to be confirmed, but this has no impact on the functionality)

Do you have any idea why is this happening, or what am I doing wrong?

Tnx.

Comment: I totally don't see faces and am logged in.

Comment: tattvamasi, you can only see faces if people who liked the page are on your friend list (do note that friend facese are not working on my non fb page, that is the reason I created this question )